# A functional relation which is satisfied by $\cos x$ and $\sin x$

Tags: calculus, analysis, recreational-mathematics, contest-math, functional-equations

Assume that the functions $f,g : \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ satisfy the relations
\begin{align}
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
f(x+y) &=& f(x)f(y)-g(x)g(y), \\
g(x+y) &=& f(x)g(y)+f(y)g(x),
\end{array}
\right. \tag{$\star$}
\end{align}
for all $x,y\in \mathbb R$.

1. Find $f,g$, if they are continuous.
2. Is there a pair functions $f,g$ satisfying $(\star)$ which are not continuous?
3. Characterization of all such pairs.

**Update.** This problem is clearly harder than the characterization of functions satisfying $$f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y),$$ as it is a system of non-linear functional equations. I imagine that, in order to attack this problem, one has to make it linear.

Comment: As these relations are satisfied by cos and sin, as you say, I am sure that they can be written in the form $A(x+y)=A(x)A(y)$ where $A(x)=\begin{pmatrix}f(x)&-g(x)\\g(x)&f(x)\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Something to do with the Wronskian of $f,g$

Comment: The equations are also satisfied by $f(x)=g(x)=0$

Comment: Harald already gave you the idea to turn your problem into pretty much the problem $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$. Call $h(x):=f(x)+ig(x)$ (this is the essentially the same as Harald is saying). Then the equations $(\star)$ are equivalent to $h(x+y)=h(x)h(y)$. Now, you can find that all continuous solutions of this are $h(x)=e^{Cx}$, or $h(x)=0$.

Comment: For 2. you can use a discontinuous solution of $r(x+y)=r(x)+r(y)$ and put $h(x):=e^{ir(x)}$, i.e. $f(x)=\sin(r(x))$ and $g(x)=\cos(r(x))$.

Comment: @ABC: Indeed your comment provides a characterization of all the continuous pairs and existence of $2^{\mathfrak c}$ discontinuous pairs. I guess, the only thing remaining to call it fully solved is a characterization of all such pairs - See edited version of the question.

Comment: All solutions of $(\star)$ arise from the solutions of $h(x+y)=h(x)h(y)$, which in turn arise form the solutions of, Cauchy's functional equation, $r(x+y)=r(x)+r(y)$, by $h(x)=e^{r(x)}$. Well, except $h(x)=0$.

Comment: Unfortunately, not all them arise in this way, as logarithm is not definable in $\mathbb C\smallsetminus\{0\}$.

Comment: Logarithm is definable in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$. You are confusing defining with defining-in-a-way-that-is-continuous. We  just need it to be defined and to hold $\ln(xy)=\ln(x)+\ln(y)$. We don't need continuity of log in all of $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: Can you prove what you are claiming? So, you need to prove that there exists an inverse of the exponential satisfying $ln(x^ay^b)=a\ln x+b\ln y$, $a,b\in\mathbb Q$ and $x,y\in\mathbb C$. (Apparently it is not possible, as such inverse ha to be continuous!)

Comment: What you are saying is correct. The definition of log below doesn't  satisfy $\ln(xy)=\ln(x)+\ln(y)$.

Comment: Still we can prove it. We just have to work directly with $h(x+y)=h(x)h(y)$ without using the $\ln$. Let me add it below.

Comment: @MarkBennet $f(x)=1$ and $g(x)=0$ will also do.

Answer (score 4):

Let me put together all in an answer.

Define $h(x):=g(x)+if(x)$. Then $(\star)$ is equivalent to $$h(x+y)=h(x)h(y).$$

If $h(x)=0$ for some $x$ then $h$ is identically zero. Assume that $h$ never vanishes.

Let $\{a_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a Hamel basis of $\mathbb{R}$ as $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space.

Put $b_i:=h(a_i)$ and define $\hat{h}(x):=e^{r(x)}$, where $r(x)$ is the unique function determined by $r(x+y)=r(x)+r(y)$, and $r(a_i)=c_i$, where $c_i$ is any number such that $e^{c_i}=b_i$, and in the sequel I will not use anything beyond this).

Then $u(x):=h(x)/\hat{h}(x)$ satisfies $u(x+y)=u(x)u(y)$, and $u(0)=1$.

If $x=\sum\frac{p_i}{q_i}a_i$, with $(p_i,q_i)=1$, then $u(x)^{\prod q_i}=\prod u(\frac{p_i}{q_i}a_i)^{\prod q_i}=1$. The last equality is because $u(\frac{p_i}{q_i}a_i)^{q_i}=u(p_ia_i)=u(a_i)^{p_i}=1$

Then $u$ is a character (group homomorphism from $\mathbb{R}$ to the unit circle).

Converselly, for every $r$ such that $r(x+y)=r(x)+r(y)$ and a character $u$ of $\mathbb{R}$ we get $h(x):=e^{r(x)}u(x)$, which satisfies $h(x+y)=h(x)h(y)$. This gives us $$f(x):=\text{Im}(h(x))$$ and $$g(x):=\text{Re}(h(x)).$$

Now, to finish, we need to 'compute' all characters of the additive group $\mathbb{R}$.

Notice that each $\frac{p}{q}\mapsto u(\frac{p}{q}a_i)$ is a character of the additive group $\mathbb{Q}$. And conversely, if $u_i$ are characters of $\mathbb{Q}$ then $$u(x)=u\left(\sum\frac{p_i}{q_i}a_i\right):=\prod u_i\left(\frac{p_i}{q_i}\right)$$ satisfies $u(x+y)=u(x)u(y)$, and $u(0)=1$.

So, what we need is to 'compute' all characters of $\mathbb{Q}$. This can be read [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/characterQ.pdf), for example.

Notice the above gives us a way to produce all the solutions $h$, but it is not a unique writing of them. If we get two $\hat{h}$'s which quotient is a character of $\mathbb{R}$ then we can obtain the same $h$ from them by dividing by this character.